# npm ERR! when installing firebase tools in gitlab CI/CD

Tags: node.js, firebase, ionic-framework, npm, gitlab-ci.yml

I am trying to integrate my **Ionic app with Angular** into **Gitlab CI/CD**.

When running the jobs, my deploy job fails every time.

The pipeline runs until the command  `- npm config set unsafe-perm true`
without any problems.

Then I want to install the firebase tools with  `- npm i -g firebase-tools`. After that many things happen and a few thousand lines later, there is always this error message.

```
2305 npm timing command:i Completed in 24044ms
2306 npm ERR! code 12307npm ERR! path /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/protobufjs
2308 npm ERR! command failed
2309 npm ERR! command sh -c -- node scripts/postinstall
2310 npm ERR! internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
2311 npm ERR!     throw err;
2312 npm ERR!     ^
2313 npm ERR! 
2314 npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/protobufjs/scripts/postinstall'
2315 npm ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
2316 npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
2317 npm ERR!     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
2318 npm ERR!     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
2319 npm ERR!     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
2320 npm timing npm Completed in 24194ms
2321 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2322 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-10-27T00_16_16_747Z-debug-0.log
2324 Cleaning up project directory and file based variables00:01
2326 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Before the first jobs start, I use a workaround with nvm to install the Node version I use in the project.

```
stages:

- build
- deploy

default:
tags:
 - nodejs

before_script:
 - node --version
 - curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
 - export NVM_DIR="$(\[ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" \] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
 - \[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
 - nvm ls-remote
 - nvm install v16.18.0
 - node --version
```

After that, a job runs that builds the webapp and runs a Lint test.

```
build-webapp:
stage: build
script:
 - cd shareloc #enter the project path
 - npm i -silent
 - npm i @ionic/cli --silent
 - npx ionic build --prod
 - npm run lint

# - npm run run-e2e-tests

artifacts:
expire_in: 10 mins
paths:
 - shareloc/www/
```

And finally, when a merge request is pushed to the master, a deploy should be run. We want to host our app on Firebase.
I have already found on the Internet that the command
`npm config set unsafe-perm true`
should help, however nothing has changed.

```
deploy-webapp:
stage: deploy
script:
    - cd shareloc #enter the project path
    - npm config set unsafe-perm true
# - npm install --unsafe-perm -g firebase-tools
    - npm i -g firebase-tools
    - npx firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN

only:
 - master
```

### My technology stack:

- Ionic 6.20.3
- Node 16.18.0
- Firebase